# Microsoft.Interop.Excel with Visual Studio 2012 no longer working

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, excel-interop

I was using a DLL from a coworker and wanted to merge their project into a single solution for maintainability reasons.  Their DLL reads data rows out of an Excel sheet, my application takes the data and displays it in a listview control. The coworker developed their part in Visual Studio 2008, while my application was developed in Visual Studio 2012.  All of the code is written in C#.

After merging the project, I had to update the reference of Microsoft.Interop.Excel to the 14.0 object library in VS2012.  When I test using the updated solution on my machine, everything works just great - the Excel file is read and everything looks good; however, when I run it on a test machine, the application no longer works.  It does not appear to read the data out of the Excel sheet.

My machine is running Office 2013, while the other machines are running Office 2010.  I tried it on another machine running Office 2010 and VS2012 and no problems.  I also tried downloading the MS redistributables, but did not have any luck.

Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: You need to determine which version of Office you want to use.  The dll you are required to reference to support Office 2010 vs Office 2013 is different.  You would have to reference both versions of the dll to support both.  If you want to support both versions have two different versions of the project.

Comment: In theory you have just to make sure that you are accounting for the DLL associated with the given Office version, that is, if you want to develop a program for Office 2010, you would have to do it from a computer having Office 2010 installed. This is the theory, but I have observed myself a really weird behaviour: if I try to create and Excel/Word application for Office 2010 (this is the version installed on my computer), everything goes fine with VS 2010, but the same code cannot be compiled in VS 2008?! Thus, you shouln't develop for Office 2010 or later from VS 2008.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I imagined it had to do with a versioning difference.  Good to know an answer now!